# Syntaxhighlighter and Tiny MCE

Tags: tinymce, syntaxhighlighter

I've used this plugin: https://github.com/RichGuk/syntaxhl to get syntaxhighlighter support via tinymce. this works fine (i dont see the highlighter at time of editing, but thats no problem)

i send the whole thing asynchron to my server and get the whoile thing updated in a div after the editor.
but if i get this update, i have already done

```
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
```

so my question is, is it possible to run this command twice (well its not, but is there an other way to render the whole site from start) when i recieve a new post? i tried calling .all(); on every update but that doesnt work.

**and a second small question:**

if i add code with much text in a line, so a linebreak is needed, the SyntaxHighlighter doens't show me the right row count. heres a small figure http://www.myimg.de/?img=Unbenannt7292d.png (the code in the screenshoot doesn't belong to the problem)

please help me! thanks!!

Comment: if i use  SyntaxHighlighter.highlight(); i get an alert "couldn't load brush js" but the script is running fine, can i disable this?